# Qt, How does QMutex work ? it seem didn't work

Tags: qt

My code as follow:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyThread myThread1;
    MyThread myThread2;
    myThread1.start();
    myThread2.start();

    qDebug("Hello World");

    myThread1.wait();
    qDebug("myThread1 is finished...");
    myThread2.wait();
    qDebug("myThread2 is finished...");

    return 0;
}
```

>

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();
};
```

>

```
void MyThread::run()
{
    QMutex mutex();
    int x = 10000;
    mutex.lock();

    while(x != 0) {
        sleep(1);
        qDebug("%d, x = %d ", thread()->currentThreadId(), x);
        x--;
    }

    mutex.unlock();
}
```

**But the result is :**

```
Hello World
5516, x = 10000 
6060, x = 10000 
5516, x = 9999 
6060, x = 9999 
5516, x = 9998 
6060, x = 9998 
5516, x = 9997 
6060, x = 9997
...
...
```

I want to the result is :

```
xxxx: 10000 
xxxx:  9999 
xxxx:  9998 
xxxx:  9997 
... 
... 
xxxx:     1

yyyy: 10000 
yyyy:  9999 
... 
...  
yyyy:     1
```

**why?   where is my fault ?  And how to use QMutex.. Thank you ...**

Comment: What's the point in threading when you want to run the tasks sequentially?

Comment: still... do you want thread two to start only when thread one is done? If so, why do you have two threads? there are lot of things which are not correct in your code, but I am not sure what you are trying to do. Explain just a bit, please.

Comment: In fact, i just want to know how to use QMutex..o(∩_∩)o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating the mutex within the scope of the run call. If you wanted the mutex to halt/delay exectution of the thread2 you would need to declare so that your objects don't create their own mutex each time.

```
// .h
class MyThread {
   ...
private:
 static QMutex mutex;
}


// .cpp
QMutex MyThread::mutex; 



// .cpp
void MyThread::run()
{
  QMutexLocker lock(&mutex)

  // do stuff then return 
  // and the mutex will be unlocked when 
  // you leave this scope
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mutex object is a local object. The threads are therefore using a different mutex and locking one does not affect the other.

To fix it, move the `QMutex` object somewhere where both threads can access it. For example, make it a global variable.

Also it's easier to use RAII-style `QMutexLocker` in functions instead of calling `lock()` and `unlock()` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the developper's explanation [here](http://woboq.com/blog/internals-of-qmutex-in-qt5.html).

It is a fine bit of lock-free programming, pretty difficult to re-implement and even more difficult to debug and validate.

However, it points to Linux [futexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex), which `QMutex` uses on Linux platforms.
You might want to use that if portability is not an issue.

This answers your question label.

However, in your particular case you don't really need that. Just create a global mutex shared by all your worker threads should do the trick.